# Call a function with an AlertDialog

Tags: javascript, save, titanium, alert, android-alertdialog

I've just started learning javascript and i'm currently making a small notepad like app. When i save the text it's saved to an uneditable text area on a seperate window.

I'd like to add a confirmation alert window to my app. When the "submit" button is pressed it should open an alert with two buttons (Confirm, Cancel).

"Confirm" should save the textArea text as the submit button currently does and "Cancel" should cancel any actions. I managed to find one example of this but being the newbie that i am i couldn't implement it without errors.
Got this code:

```
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (textArea.value != "") {
        var newFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "newFile.txt");

        if (!newFile.exists()) {
            newFile.write();
            newFile.write(textArea.value);
            textArea02.value = textArea.value;
        } else {
            var fileContent = newFile.read();
            var newContent = fileContent.text + " " + textArea.value;

            newFile.write(newContent);
            textArea02.value = newContent;

            alert("File Saved");
        }

        textArea.value = "";
        textArea.blur();

    } else {
        alert("Enter some text to save");
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive of the error you are getting? You ask about how to do a confirmation dialog, but then your code seems to be about errors when writing text to a file. I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't currently get any errors when i save, i just don't know how to implement the AlertDialog functions correctly within the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
var alertDialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
    title: 'Confirm',
    message: 'Are you sure?',
    buttonNames: [ 'No', 'Yes' ],
    cancel: 0 // index to the cancel button
});
alertDialog.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    if (evt.index /* if it's 1, they hit Yes */) {
        alert('OK!');
    }
});
alertDialog.show();
```